# Lightbox2, how to show all images

Tags: views, javascript

I have a views with 6 images per page. When I click on image lightbox shows only those 6 images on current page. I want lightbox to show all images of current node, how can I do this?

Comment: I had to do this several times, I always solved this using display:none on the extra images... but I hope you find a better (ajax?) solution for us.

Comment: Can I see the page?